# Aggregating categorical variables to one variable in python 3 pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns. like this

```
ID  col1                        col2                col3
1   Strongly Positive   Strongly Positive   Weekly Positive
2   Strongly Positive   Strongly Positive   Neutral
3   Strongly Negative   Strongly Negative   Weekly Negative
4   Weekly Negative      Strongly Negative  Neutral
5   Neutral              Neutral            Neutral
6   Strongly Positive   Strongly Negative   Strongly Negative
7   Strongly Negative   Weekly Positive     Neutral
8   Neutral               Weekly Negative   Weekly Positive
```

Each of the columns can take values like (strongly positive, weekly positive, Neutral, weekly negative and strongly negative and an ID column.
I need to create a new column with these logic

1. If all the column has positive values or atleast one positive and two neutral values then aggregate that record in the new column as positive
2. If all the three column has neutral value then flag as neutral
3. If all the columns have negative values or atleast one negative and two neutral values then flag it as negative
4. If both positive and negative values are thre then flag it as both
   by positive i mean either strong or weekly positive and the same for negative as well.

I need the the final data frame to be like this

```
ID  col1                  col2          col3        Aggregated_Col
1   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive Weekly Positive    Positive
2   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive Neutral            Positive
3   Strongly Negative  Strongly Negative Weekly Negative    Negative
4   Weekly Negative    Strongly Negative Neutral            Negative
5   Neutral            Neutral       Neutral                Neutral
6   Strongly Positive  Strongly Negative Strongly Negative  Both
7   Strongly Negative  Weekly Positive   Neutral            Both
8   Neutral Weekly     Negative      Weekly Positive        Both
```

Not able to think of a logic

```
ID  col1                  col2          col3        Aggregated_Col
1   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive Weekly Positive    Positive
2   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive Neutral            Positive
3   Strongly Negative  Strongly Negative Weekly Negative    Negative
4   Weekly Negative    Strongly Negative Neutral            Negative
5   Neutral            Neutral       Neutral            Neutral
6   Strongly Positive  Strongly Negative Strongly Negative  Both
7   Strongly Negative  Weekly Positive   Neutral            Both
8   Neutral Weekly     Negative      Weekly Positive    Both
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Interesting Outside-Of-Box Solution

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

a = df.to_numpy().astype(str)
b = np.select([find(a, 'Pos') >= 0, find(a, 'Neg') >= 0], [1, -1], 0)

c = np.select(
    [(b == 0).all(1), (b >=0).all(1), (b <= 0).all(1)],
    ['Neutral', 'Positive', 'Negative'],
    'Both'
)

df.assign(Agg=c)

                 col1               col2               col3       Agg
ID                                                                   
1   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive    Weekly Positive  Positive
2   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive            Neutral  Positive
3   Strongly Negative  Strongly Negative    Weekly Negative  Negative
4     Weekly Negative  Strongly Negative            Neutral  Negative
5             Neutral            Neutral            Neutral   Neutral
6   Strongly Positive  Strongly Negative  Strongly Negative      Both
7   Strongly Negative    Weekly Positive            Neutral      Both
8             Neutral    Weekly Negative    Weekly Positive      Both
```

---

#### Slightly Different Take

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

a = df.to_numpy().astype(str)
b = np.select([find(a, 'Pos') >= 0, find(a, 'Neg') >= 0], [1, -1], 0)

m = {
    (0, 0): 'Neutral', (1, -1): 'Both',
    (1, 1): 'Positive', (1, 0): 'Positive',
    (-1, -1): 'Negative', (0, -1): 'Negative',
}

df.assign(Agg=[*map(m.get, zip(b.max(1), b.min(1)))])

                 col1               col2               col3       Agg
ID                                                                   
1   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive    Weekly Positive  Positive
2   Strongly Positive  Strongly Positive            Neutral  Positive
3   Strongly Negative  Strongly Negative    Weekly Negative  Negative
4     Weekly Negative  Strongly Negative            Neutral  Negative
5             Neutral            Neutral            Neutral   Neutral
6   Strongly Positive  Strongly Negative  Strongly Negative      Both
7   Strongly Negative    Weekly Positive            Neutral      Both
8             Neutral    Weekly Negative    Weekly Positive      Both
```

Comment: I faced problem in df.to_numpy(). So pandas has to be updated to 0.24 or higher

Comment: Nah, just use `df.values`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest recoding these values to integers, e.g.

```
recode = {"Strongly Positive": 2, "Weakly Positive": 1, "Neutral": 0, "Weakly Negative": -1, "Strongly Negative": -2}
```

Then, you can write a function like this:

```
def interpret(values):
  if min(values) >= 0:
    return 1
  elif ...
```

and invoke it using `df.apply(interpret, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 columns so you can use

```
DF.apply(YourCustomFunction, axis=1)
```

Axis 1 tells you want to perform an operation on rows. Write your custom logic as a function:

```
def MyFunction(x):
    if condition1:
        Do something
    elif condition2:
        Do something
    ........
```

So passing

DF['NewCol'] = DF.apply(MyFunction, axis=1)

Will do the trick. Mind you the x passed to the function will be an array so you have to address it correctly indexing within your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the respective elements like this:

```
# set index as ID:
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

has_pos = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Positive')).any(axis=1)
has_neg = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Negative')).any(axis=1)
has_both = has_pos & has_neg

# update
df['Agg_Col'] = 'Neutral'
df.loc[has_pos,'Agg_Col'] = 'Positive'
df.loc[has_neg,'Agg_Col'] = 'Negative'

df.loc[has_both,'Agg_Col'] = 'Both'
```